# How do I return the sum of each row in a matrix as an array?

Tags: java, arrays, matrix

Yes I'm a beginner. Yes I tried google. Yes my patience failed me!

I have a task to calculate the sum of each row in the matrix m and return them as an array. This little piece is what I've come up with so far. But where do I declare the array? I think I need to make sum to an array and not an int. Thanks in advance for your help!

```
public static int sum(int[][] m) {
for(int i = 0; i < m.length; i++){    
    int sum = 0;    
        for(int j = 0; j < m[0].length; j++){    
            sum = sum + m[i][j];    
            }    

            return sum;
        } 
 }
```

Comment: Have a look at https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/program-to-find-the-sum-of-each-row-and-each-column-of-a-matrix/

Comment: If you are supposed to return an array, your return type should be an array type, e.g. `int[]`, not `int`. Also, if you `return` in the middle of a subloop, it will never get to the next row, will it?

Comment: You need: to know how to find how many rows there are, to allocate an array to hold the sums for that many rows, to sum an individual row, to put that sum into the array of sums, to do the last two steps in a loop for each row, and, finally, to return the int[] of sums.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were close! Just need the Array declared outside the loops.

```
public static int[] sum(int[][] m) {
  int[] sums = new int[m.length];
  for(int i = 0; i < m.length; i++) {
    sums[i] = 0;
    for (int j = 0; j < m[i].length; j++) {
      sums[i] += m[i][j];
    }
  }
  return sums;
}
```

Comment: @ebz No prob, mate! Good luck on the rest of your assignment(s)!

Answer (score 0):

You could also do this, in a more functional way:

```
public static int[] sum(int[][] m) {
  return Arrays.stream(m)
    .mapToInt(arr -> Arrays.stream(arr).sum())
    .toArray();
}
```

Comment: Wow! Never would've thought about that. Thanks